# VueJs: Removing item from middle of array re-renders all subsequent items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects which are looped over in a Vue template, each contains `<input>`s. User’s have a button to add additional items to the array - these are rendered - that all works perfectly. **Each new component is given a unique key**.

Users are able to remove any of the added `<input>`s using a button. This works correctly in the `data.repeats` array - the item is removed. The DOM is also updated to remove this item.

However, **if I have 4 items and remove the second, items 3 and 4 will be re-rendered** (I can see they were ‘updated’ in in Vue dev tools). This will loose any data added to those inputs (or changes to DOM etc.).

It’s only items after the removed one that this happens to.

From my understanding, by using `:key` on the component Vue should be able to track it and re-render.

I thought it might be because I was storing the items in an array and when removing one in the centre all the keys after decremented by one so I tried using an object with named properties which never change but the result in the DOM is the same - all items after the removed one get re-rendered.

Is there way to stop this?

```
<div v-for="(repeat, count) in repeats">
    <template v-for="field in repeat">
        <component
            :is="field.component" 
            :content="field.content"
            :key="field.content.dot_name"
        >
        </component>
    </template>

    <button @click="remove(count)">Remove</button>
</div>

<button @click="add">Add</button>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        repeats: []
    }
},

methods: {
    add() {
        this.repeats.push(this.cloneFields());
    },
    remove(key) {
        this.repeats.splice(key, 1);
    },
}
```

**Added items:**

Three items added with data in `input`s (green):

[image]

Vue tools showing items:

[image]

.

**Remove item:**

Middle item removed - and data gone from the last item (the remove button shows the loop index):

[image]

Vue tools showing the removed item and `:key` still the same for last item (...diaries.**3**.sub...) `client_details.subsidiaries.3.subsidiary_company_name`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a key to `v-for="(repeat, count) in repeats"` loop

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work - I added the key to the loop and updated the component key to use it but if I remove item ‘1’ the value of item ‘2’ becomes 1. The DOM item is removed correctly and values remain but the inputs all ‘move down a place’ and take the lower value. 3 -> 2, 2 -> 1... etc.

Comment: Don't use indexes, assign unique ids to all of your objects and then use those as keys

Comment: I’ve added unique keys to each loop but it’s not fixed it. Still re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code count represent index so make different key for both loops

like add key (avoid a non-primitive key instead of that use string or number) to the outer loop

```
<div v-for="(repeat, count) in repeats" :key="'outer' + count">
```

and for the inner loop

```
 <template v-for="(field, index) in repeat" :key="'inner' + index">
```

Comment: This doesn’t work. Needed to make the <template> a <div> to add a key. I have a key on both looping divs and component. I’ve tried using the third index argument ‘index‘ on the loops too. It still clears the inputs.

Comment: Can you plz share more details about `this.cloneFields()` function

Comment: `cloneFields()` does a deep clone of a source object and adjusts one property used to make the unique key

Comment: Plz, check Home.vue file , might be it will help ,

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-example-forked-824rpg?file=/src/views/Home.vue:29-33

Comment: WHich version of vue you have used vue2 or vue 3 ?

Comment: It’s VueJS version 2

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
.....
<button @click="remove(item.id)">Remove</button>
```

pass the id to parameter

```
remove(id) {
  const index = this.items.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
  if (index !== -1) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```

you can try this link :
https://fontawesomeicons.com/tryit/code/vue-js-remove-item-from-array-by-id/0